# How to store output of command in variable in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i want to store output of command in variable in batch programming please help me..thanks in advance..

like i want to store output of find command in variable p
set p=find /c "chi*" "file.txt"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to store number of lines and not full line of output produced by find

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('find /c "chi*" "file.txt"') do set p=%%i
```

Note: to store full line you can use either `tokens=*` or `delims=` (no space after equal sign!).